# Android SQLite showing data by cursor in tablerows

Tags: android, sqlite, tablerow

So i've got a problem with extraction data from my SQLite database.

This is my cursor which gets data from db and it is in DatabaseAdapter class.

```
    public Cursor getAllData2() {

        String[] allColumns = new String[] {DatabaseAdapter.UID, DatabaseAdapter.WIEK, DatabaseAdapter.WZROST, DatabaseAdapter.WAGA, DatabaseAdapter.BMI, DatabaseAdapter.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = db.query(DatabaseAdapter.TABLE_NAME, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }
```

Then i'm building a table where i calling my cursor

```
    private void BuildTable() {

    Cursor cursor = bazadanych.getAllData2();

    int rows = cursor.getCount();
    int cols = cursor.getColumnCount();

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)  {
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tv.setTextSize(16);
                tv.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);

                tv.setText(cursor.getString(j));

                row.addView(tv);

            }
        cursor.moveToNext();
        tabela.addView(row);

    }

}
```

And after that i call BuildTable(); after clicking on button.
And nothing happens.

XML file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/wczytaj"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabela"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="382dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
    android:layout_weight="2.02"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:text="ID" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Wiek" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Wzrost" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Waga" />

        <TextView
            android:text="BMI" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Data" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

When i delete all TableRow i've got error divided by 0.

Comment: Um... you are calling several times movetofirst. How many data do you actually have?

Comment: WHat means nothign happens? No data is introduced?

Comment: i've got about 6 columns, yes nothing is showing at all

Comment: How many lines or entries in the table do you have?

Comment: I'm adding entries into table when i press button, but always stay there is 6 columns.

Comment: Solved error on table creation. This line need to be changed
row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 

To

   row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19343 - found this here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This row need to be changed:

```
row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Into this:

```
tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19343 here is the answer